# Django project on google app engine without django-nonrel

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am trying to build a simple static site using django. since, Google App Engine provides django's template engine I don't want to unnecessarily use django-nonrel as for now.

So, I created my django app using `django-admin.py startproject mysite`

In that I added `app.yaml`, `__init__.py`
The root folder looks like below

```
/myappname/
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    app.yaml
    mysite/ settings.py, wsgi.py/ urls.py, __init__.py
```

The app.yaml file settings are below

```
application: myappname
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: /mysite/wsgi.py

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.4"
```

Now, when I try to run the site, i am getting

google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: /mysite/wsgi.py

I turned off threadsafe, this time I didn't get any error but only seeing a blank while screen.. and views are not working.

Where I am going wrong? how should I fix it?

Comment: Does it run fine on your local machine? When you say "not working", do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a bit of information out there on how to deploy a Django app on GAE. Google and read through some of them.

I do not understand "*Google App Engine provides django's template engine I don't want to unnecessarily use django-nonrel as for now*".

Django non-rel is a flavour of Django that works with the non-rel database of GAE. It has nothing to do with Django's built in template engine AFAIK. If you decide to not go with the non-rel version you will have to connect to Google Cloud SQL (Google's implementation of MySQL in the cloud, which unfortunately no longer has a free offering).

Your `app.yaml` probably needs:

```
builtins:
- django_wsgi: on
```

Otherwise you need to provide more information as "only seeing a blank screen and views are not working" is too sparse to diagnose.